# View NetCDF tables in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, netcdf

The Multidimension Tools in ArcMap allow extracting tables of data from NetCDF files.

When I batch run the Make NetCDF Table View tool 10x (eg extracting time series at multiple locations), only the outputs of the final row of the batch operation are visible in the Table of Contents.

When trying to recreate tables 1-9, Arc says that tables with those names already exist, even though I can't see them. So the batch process must have worked in some way.

How can I gain access to the tables that aren't visible in the Table of Contents?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify whether  you are using ArcMap or Pro, and which version.

Comment: Sounds odd, try running the tool a couple of times extracting 1 layer see if the issue of it not adding them to the contents pane happens?

Comment: Updated question to refer to ArcMap. ArcGIS Pro doesn't allow batching this tool.